# Можно ли сделать список значений с помощью только одного ввода input?

Tags: python

Мне нужно создать список из большого количества значений, которые должен ввести пользователь. Запрашивать каждое из них с помощью отдельной строки input не очень хорошо. Можно ли ввести все данные с помощью одной строки? Что-то вроде этого:

```py
list = []

list[1], list[2], list[3] = input('Введите знач.: ')
```

Только этот код завершается падением

Comment: `lst = [float(x) for x in input('Введите значения, разделенные пробелом: ').split()]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод split вернет список разделенный условиями. Разделять можно по любому значению " ", "/", ":"и тд.
После выполнения условия переменная "a" станет списком

```
a = input("").split(" ")
print(a)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Такой параметр для `split` не имеет смысла указывать, дефолтный параметр ничем не хуже

Comment: @CrazyElf согласен, но такой пример более нагляден.